# joomla 2.5 / K2 - SQL Query to delete trashed items taking care of data integrity

Tags: joomla-2.5, k2, sql

I have not a testing environment where put this to the test:

```
delete from k2_items where trash = 1
```

Of course this will remove everything that is marked as trash, but is there any other table that has data linked to this one creating relational integrity that i can damage by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K2 is not using cascade delete : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

It's is safe to run your query. Only trashed articles will be delete.

You can and should do a backup of your table. This is a good practice.

Comment: I did a backup of the table first just in case something went wrong; it worked perfectly. Thanks!